# Congruence with $x$ in a power

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I don't know how to find $x$ in a situation like this:

$$a^x \equiv b \pmod c$$

I think I'm missing something around little fermat theorem, Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the *discrete log* problem and is not trivial, unless you know a primitive root for $c$. For small $c$ you can of course simply keep multiplying by $a$ until you get $b$.

Comment: What if I can't use brutal force? $$ 6^x = 4 (mod 19) $$ Could you show me step-by-step solution?